# Parsing html using Beautiful Soup in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<title>CATe - hj1612</title>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td><td><img src="icons/arrowredright.gif"/></td><td align="center">
<input name="keyt" type="hidden" value="a3dvl"/>
<input type="submit" value="View"/><br/>or<br/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to get the value of `keyt`. As it is `html` I am using `BeautifulSoup`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

and I know you can use `soup.find` with `id` like `soup.find(id="randomid")`

but `soup.find(name="keyt")`  will not work as it is not a body tag ... as a result I thouht I would use the normal `if substring in string:` method so

```
for line in soup.find_all('input'):
    if "keyt" in line:
        print line
```

but this method doesnt seem to work, I am new to python so would appreciate any help/pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>CATe - hj1612</title>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td><td><img src="icons/arrowredright.gif"/></td><td align="center">
<input name="keyt" type="hidden" value="a3dvl"/>
<input type="submit" value="View"/><br/>or<br/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</td>
</tr>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find(name="input", attrs={'name': 'keyt'})
```

Output:

```
<input name="keyt" type="hidden" value="a3dvl"/>
```

You can use the `find_all` function instead of `find` if you want to find multiple occurrences. As for how to use the two functions, `name` is the name of the tag that you want to find, and the `attrs` dict is what you *really* use to find things with particular attributes, in your case, the `name` attribute.

Comment: @user2897415 Make a separate question for this, since it _is_ separate.

Answer (score 0):

You have some strange HTML. HEAD Tag is not closed, td, table is not opened. I can't even imagine, how soup can parse it.

Comment: Honestly, it does not matter.